# How to add a imagejudgement in json decode foreach

Tags: php, json

How to add a imagejudgement in json decode foreach. if there is a `jpg,png,gif` in the end, so that echo `html_entity_decode($result->url)`, else not. thanks.

```
foreach ($data->query->allimages as $result) {
echo '<img src="'.html_entity_decode($result->url).'" /><br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So please try this:

```
foreach ($data->query->allimages as $result) {
    $path = pathinfo($result->url);
    if(!in_array($path['extension'], array('jpg','png','gif'))) continue;
    echo '<img src="'.html_entity_decode($result->url).'" /><br/>'."\n";
}
```

Comment: @Marc Grabow, it not worled, still output some file like `.wav` .

Comment: So you want to skip every file which is not in array('jpg','png','gif')? I thought you only want to encode them not.

Comment: @Marc Grabow, ` I thought you only want to encode them not. ` how to do that?

Comment: Not encode them? That's what I've posted in my first solution - now I changed the answer in the way all not jpg,png,gif files are skipped - That's what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: @Marc Grabow, sorry, i ve not see you had edited your answer. this is what I need. thank u a lot.

Comment: Yep, I should say that the next time... :)